# Single Activity Architecture, will nav_graph getting so big?

Tags: android

i just learned about Single Activity Architecture with NavigationComponent.
And i just curious, will our nav_graph.xml get so big? because all of the destination/fragment is writen in that file

Comment: There is more information about how to create nested graphs to handle big navigations: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-nested-graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main_graph` can get bigger as destinations increase. What I usually do is create multiple navigation graphs and include them in my `main_graph` (nested nav-graphs) and write my final destinations in child graphs.